# How to print a hash in a specific order in perl

Tags: perl, hash, printing

I have an array of hashes.

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Name' => 'Bob',
      'Address' => 'Home',
      'DOB' => '01/01/1990',
      'Sex' => 'M',
    };
$VAR2 = {
      'Name' => 'Mary',
      'Address' => 'Home',
      'DOB' => '01/01/1990',
      'Sex' => 'F',
    };
```

Which I print to an xml file. However, when I print this array to an xml file I get:

```
<Record Address=Home DOB=01/01/1990 Name=Bob Sex=M />
```

Id prefer to have Name, Address, DOB, Sex.

```
<Record Name=Bob Address=Home Sex=M DOB=01/01/1990 />
```

Sorting the array by Key or Key value wouldn't put the values in the correct order either. Is there a simple solution to print the hash in the desired order?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to create the output. You can [edit] your question. The XML format seems a bit odd, like you need to use XML but don't really want to.

Comment: I would just make a little subroutine that prints out the hash the way you want it, and call that as needed.

Comment: What are you using for your XML generation? If the answer is `XML::Simple` you're probably stuck.

Comment: The question is clean and clear, I do not think it deserved downvote

Comment: XML::Simple is used.

Answer (score 6):

Hashes are [*explicitly* unordered](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks). So no, you can't do that. There's only two ways of maintaining order (with a `hash`):

- use an array to enforce ordering with a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).
- Use a sort function that returns keys in the order you desire.

Something like:

```
my @fields = qw (  Name Address DOB Sex );
my @ordered_values = @hash{@fields};
```

Or just a simple:

```
foreach my $key ( @fields ) {
    print "$key=$hash{$key} "; 
}
```

Although, if you're working with XML... it may be there's better ways to handle your  source data than stuffing it into a hash in the first place.

I would note - when writing XML, you wouldn't typically inline key-values in the content of the XML, but rather as attributes (or children elements):

```
<Record Address="Home" DOB="01/01/1990" Name="Bob" Sex="M" />
```

Or:

```
<Record>
   <Address>Home</Address> 
   <DOB>01/01/1990</DOB>
   <Name>Bob</Name>
   <Sex>M</Sex>
</Record>
```

Because by doing so, then you can use the XML query tools to match specific criteria (like `xpath`).

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, there is no better alternatives